# LaravelExcel: Evaluate Calculation when export to CSV

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I am using Laravel Excel: http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs for Laravel 5+

I am trying to convert an XLSX file to a CSV file. This is working fine, except that in the resulting CSV file the calculations are not evaluated, and are returned as "plain text" (for example: `"=IF(A1="YES";TRUE;FALSE)"` )

This is how I try to do it now, but apparently this is not working:

```
   $file = $request->file('file');            
   $result = Excel::load($file, function($file) {})->download("csv");
```

is there another method that allows me to export the file to CSV while evaluating the cells, or do I need to create my own loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is just an option for that in the config file...

```
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Pre-calculate formulas during export
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'calculate'                   => true,
```